# Check from xcode what accounts have root privileges

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm getting the list of accounts from OSX background process (aka daemon) with help of `CBIdentity`. However, there seems to be no information whenever or not each `CBIdentity` has admin rights. Maybe someone knows how to get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `CBIdentity` instance is member of admin group with `isMemberOfGroup:` method. To get admin group you can create `CBGroupIdentity` with needed GID. List of all GIDs can be found in `/etc/group` and probably needed for your purposes record is `staff:*:20:root`.

```
- (BOOL) isIdentityAdmin:(CBIdentity *)identity
{
    gid_t adminGID = 20;
    CBGroupIdentity* adminGroup = [CBGroupIdentity groupIdentityWithPosixGID:adminGID authority:[CBIdentityAuthority defaultIdentityAuthority]];
    return [identity isMemberOfGroup:adminGroup];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpfull!